# Reverse recovery current + diode

Tags: semiconductor-physics

The reverse recovery current of a diode is due to accumulated charges in the P and N region during it forward stat. I want to know this current is a diffusion current or a drift current?

Comment: Depends on whether you are applying voltage to the diode or not.

Comment: While moving to the new equilibrium, there will be diffusion current (as always) and built-in field driven drift current.

Comment: Can you explain how this question is different from [your earlier one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175337/26969)?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is the same Floris, I am sorry for this issue.